# Using reduceByKey with case in scala

Tags: scala, mapreduce, case, reduce, bigdata

I have this type ;

```
 column1 column2 int 
 ((a,b),1)
 ((a,c),1)
 ((k,a),1)
```

I need two types results,firstly total of column1 for all column2

```
(a,total)
```

and secondly column1 parameter is not equal to column2 parameter

```
(a,total)
```

How can i use ReduceByKey For this type ?

my codes :

```
var data = sc.textFile("tttt.tsv")
var satir = data.map(line=> ((line.split("\t")(1).toString,line.split("\t")(2).toString),1))
```

---About Second Scenario

My data type example is

```
column1 column2 int
a b,1 
a c,1
a a,1
a d,1
```

I need reduceByKey for column1  is not equal column1 in second scenario

for example,my example data result  = (a,b,1) + (a,c,1)+(a,d,1) = 3

Comment: can you explain second scenario more

Comment: i added somethings about second scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, below is one way to get what you're asking:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (("a", "b"), 1),
  (("a", "c"), 1),
  (("a", "d"), 1),
  (("a", "a"), 1),
  (("k", "k"), 1),
  (("k", "a"), 1),
  (("k", "b"), 1)
))

val rdd1 = rdd.map{ case ((x, y), c) => (x, c) }.
  reduceByKey(_ + _)

scala> rdd1.collect.foreach(println)
(a,4)
(k,3)

val rdd2 = rdd.filter{ case ((x, y), c) => x != y }.
  map{ case ((x, y), c) => (x, c) }.
  reduceByKey(_ + _)

scala> rdd2.collect.foreach(println)
(a,3)
(k,2)
```

Comment: Hi Leo C,Thank you so much your answer, I have two correct rdd. Do you have an idea  how can i join this tow RDD ? (For Example 
(a,4) and secondly (a,3), how can i join (a,4,3)  ? )

Comment: Glad that it helps.  You can convert the RDDs to DataFrames via `toDF("col1", "col2")` then `df1.join(df2, "col1")`.  Or you can join the RDDs like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27437507/join-two-ordinary-rdds-with-without-spark-sql).

Answer (score 0):

For First Scenario you can use this one.

```
val arrangedDF = satir.map(pairData => (pairData._1._1, (pairData._1._2, 1)))
val result1DF = arrangedDF.reduceByKey((x,y) => x._2 + y._2)
```

Here i rearranged the representation of data i separated key and put rest the data into different tuple by this you can apply `reduceByKey` directly.

For Second Scenario you can use this.

```
val result2DF = arrangedDF.filter( pairData => pairData._1 != pairData._2._1).reduceByKey((x,y) => x._2 + y._2)
```

Here for second Scenario i reused `arrangedDF` and apply filter over it for the condition you wanted that is column1 parameter not equal to column2 parameter and then applied `reduceByKey`

Hope my answer was clear

Thanks

Comment: Hi,Thank you so much your answer ; When i tried your answer,scala :

scala> val result1DF = arrangedDF.reduceByKey((x,y) => x._2 + y._2)
<console>:30: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: (String, Int)
       val result1DF = arrangedDF.reduceByKey((x,y) => x._2 + y._2)